# Include content of subdomain inside a block or view?

Tags: views, nodes, blocks, subsites

I have created a subdomain - example sub.homepage.com. The subdomain is pointing to a server. But I need the template to be the same as my website.

My question:
Can I somehow include the content of that subdomain inside a block or view, or something else?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer on this.

I've created a new block, added this:

```
<?php print file_get_contents("http://sub.homepage.com/"); ?>
```

Remember textformat should be PHP.

And it worked. It now shows my subdomain inside my template.